# How to add a DNS alias programmatically?

Tags: c#, dns

I want to create an alias record in Microsoft's DNS server to point AliasA to ComputerA. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used WMI to do this, found an example on the web, and this is what it looked like.

```
   private ManagementScope _session = null;

   public ManagementPath CreateCNameRecord(string DnsServerName, string ContainerName, string OwnerName, string PrimaryName)
    {
        _session = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + DnsServerName+ "\\root\\MicrosoftDNS", con);
        _session.Connect();

        ManagementClass zoneObj = new ManagementClass(_session, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_CNAMEType"), null);
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = zoneObj.GetMethodParameters("CreateInstanceFromPropertyData");
        inParams["DnsServerName"] = ((System.String)(DnsServerName));
        inParams["ContainerName"] = ((System.String)(ContainerName));
        inParams["OwnerName"] = ((System.String)(OwnerName));
        inParams["PrimaryName"] = ((System.String)(PrimaryName));
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = zoneObj.InvokeMethod("CreateInstanceFromPropertyData", inParams, null);

        if ((outParams.Properties["RR"] != null))
        {
            return new ManagementPath(outParams["RR"].ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: ``con`` is undefined. `System.Management.ConnectionOptions` Which parameters did you set there?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.management.connectionoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It's been 8 years, that was a one off automation project I put together. If you don't specify any options it uses the currently logged on user for authentication so that is probably what I used, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .NET has anything to provide access to these (all I can find in a bit of quick searching is references to proprietary libraries, controls, etc.), so you'll probably have to use the Win32 API via P/Invoke (though another possibility would be to do the job via WMI).

You'd start with [`DnsAcquireContextHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682007(VS.85).aspx), then (probably) [`DnsQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682016(v=VS.85).aspx) to get a current record set, modify its contents to add your new alias, [`DnsReplaceRecordSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682031(v=VS.85).aspx) to have the DNS server use the new set of records, and finally [`DnsReleaseContextHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682029(v=VS.85).aspx) to shut things down.

Of course, you'll need the right permissions on the server or none of this will work at all.